# Is it possible to make a swipe navigation with StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, stack-navigator

I am a new user of react navigation. I would like to know if it was possible to create swipe navigation to swipe between Stack with StackNavigator?

I have already tried the method with Tabnavigator:

```
 swipeEnabled: true,
 tabBarOptions: {
   style: { display: "none" }
```

but this is not my expectation because I have multi routes and many returns

Comment: do you mean swipe between Tabs or swap to go back to previous page?

Comment: if you want to go back with swipe gesture you can set gestureEnabled:true in StackNavigator options

Answer (score 0):

You can. 
But I do not recommend use swipe on StackNavigator included in TapNavigation. 
It can cause confusion to users.

For example, while user use some screen of StackNavigation, he/she will not easy to expect whether change tap. Especially the swipe from left to right.

- Swipe on TapNavigation: Change screens added on TapBar.
- Swipe on StackNavigation: Move back to previous screen stacked.

But if you use TapNavigation in StackNavigation, it is OK cause `TapBar` will be covered by screens of StackNavigation.